# Preciso contar a frequência relativa de cada letra numa string

Tags: java

Preciso que este código conte a frequência de cada letra, espaço, ponto, vírgula e números. Sou iniciante em Java e não estou sabendo alterar este código. Ele só conta as letras. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite uma palavra/frase");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    s = s.toLowerCase();

    System.out.println("Character\tFrequency");
    for(char ch= 'a' ; ch<='z' ; ch++ ){
        int c=0;
        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            if(ch == s.charAt(i)) c++;
        }
        if(c!=0)
        System.out.println(ch+ "\t\t " + c);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Acho que o mais indicado é mudar para algo [assim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17995206) (somente até o primeiro `for`, já que o restante faz outra coisa). Enfim, esse código conta qualquer caractere, mas pode adaptar para só incluir na contagem se o caractere estiver na lista dos que vc quer contar

Comment: Você teria que usar map para fazer essa contagem e pecorrer todos os caracteres da string ao invés de pecorrer todas as letras do alfabeto e verificar e se existe na string.

Answer (score -3):

Eu só alterei o inicio do primeiro for para o espaço e ele passou a contar tudo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContaCaracter {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite uma palavra/frase");
        String s = in.nextLine();
        s = s.toLowerCase();

        System.out.println("Character\tFrequency");
        for(char ch= ' ' ; ch<='z' ; ch++ ){
            int c=0;
            for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
                if(ch == s.charAt(i)) c++;
            }
            if(c!=0)
                System.out.println(ch+ "\t\t " + c);
        }
    }

}
```